# Equivalent to tmux CTRL+B z in vim?

Tags: tmux, navigation

In tmux if you have alot of panes open, you can press CTRL+B, z to zoom into that terminal pane.  Is there a way to do the same thing in vim, to zoom into / out of the selected pane?

Comment: AFAIK, there are some plugins that simulate this, but nothing native to vim that i can think of. You could try `tabedit %` as an approximation.

Comment: One of the plugins is [zoomwin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=508) which remaps `ctrl-w o` which IMHO is a good choice. However, I would recommend to use the suggestion of @D.BenKnoble (one less plugin and works everywhere). I agree that `:tabe %` is not as short as `ctrl-w o`. At least you can close(minimize) with `ctrl-w c` since it is the only window in this tab. Just for completeness: since tabs in vim are different to tabs in gui apps, I'd recommend for those who are not familar with this to read https://stackoverflow.com/a/103590/1057593.

Comment: I use `nnoremap <C-w>t :tabsplit` for zooming in and `<c-w>q` for zooming out, or zooming in/out experience I should say.

Comment: https://redd.it/979lv2

Comment: @AS If you want to post that as the answer I think it's great!

Comment: @leeand00, Done. And agreed, it's very handy, indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use `ctrl-w |` if my screen is split vertically or `ctrl-w _` if split horizontally to zoom in. To get back, I use `ctrl-w =`.

Answer (score 3):

A nice way to do this is with `:tab split`

This will open the current buffer in a new tab where it is "zoomed".

When you are done use `:q` to close the tab and you are back to the previous window layout.

Answer (score 1):

All the credits [go](https://redd.it/979lv2) to [reddit user tLaw101](https://www.reddit.com/user/tLaw101):

```
function! WinZoomToggle() abort
    if ! exists('w:WinZoomIsZoomed') 
        let w:WinZoomIsZoomed = 0
    endif
    if w:WinZoomIsZoomed == 0
        let w:WinZoomOldWidth = winwidth(0)
        let w:WinZoomOldHeight = winheight(0)
        wincmd _
        wincmd |
        let w:WinZoomIsZoomed = 1
    elseif w:WinZoomIsZoomed == 1
        execute "resize " . w:WinZoomOldHeight
        execute "vertical resize " . w:WinZoomOldWidth
        let w:WinZoomIsZoomed = 0
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>wz :call WinZoomToggle()<CR>
```

Comment: that's isn't what I was talking about...I was talking about the `:tabedit %` and `:tabclose` answer is much better than that one, as there isn't ready anything to setup apart from maybe a keymap, it's on that page if you keep reading a bit further.

Comment: It may be much better but it's not similar in any way to tmux's `<C-b>z` :). While the function from the original post indeed replicates it.

Comment: Oh I understand, sorry AS I asked this question such a long time ago...